# How to prove comparison principle for parabolic PDE (nonlinear)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, maximum-principle

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth with $F(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$ and $F:(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ continuous and increasing with $F(0) = 0$.

Consider the PDE 
$$u_t = \Delta F(u) \quad \text{on $\Omega$}$$
$$u(x,0) = u_0$$
$$u(x,t) = C_1\quad \text{on $\partial \Omega$}$$

Suppose we have two weak solutions $u$ and $v$ in $L^2(0,T;H^1)\cap H^{-1}(0,T;H^{-1})$ with initial data $u_0$ and $v_0$ and boundary data $C_u$ and $C_v$ respectively, where
$u_0 \leq v_0$ and $C_u \leq C_v$.

How do I show that the comparison principle holds: that $u \leq v$?

Assume more smoothness of the solutions if necessary. I can't do it. I know we need to test with $(u(t)-v(t))^+$ but I don't know what to do with the nonlinear term.

Comment: Assume $u,v$ are smooth, then consider $v_\epsilon:=v+\epsilon e^t$. Obviously $v_\epsilon>u$ on the boundary and at the beginning. If $v$ doesnt stay larger than $u$, than there's a first time $t>0$ where $v-u=0$. Differentiating and exploiting that $F'>0$ gives you a contradiction. then let $\epsilon\to0$